# Task throws error=7: Argument list too long

Tags: shell, ant

I have an Ant's `build.xml` file which executes with no problems on my machine (Ubuntu), but throws the following error:

```
/var/lib/hudson/workspace/myproject/build.xml:254: Error running /var/lib/hudson/tools/java_6/bin/javac compiler
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.executeExternalCompile(DefaultCompilerAdapter.java:525)
(...)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/lib/hudson/tools/java_6/bin/javac": java.io.IOException: error=7, Argument list too long
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.executeExternalCompile(DefaultCompilerAdapter.java:522)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=7, Argument list too long
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:148)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
... 24 more
```

The argument list is quite big in fact contains all the jar files from `WEB-INF/lib` which is 231650 characters long!
Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Can you attach, or copy paste, your build.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`apply`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) for your [`fileset`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) in your `build.xml`, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="build">
  <fileset id="myfiles" dir="${basedir}">
    <include name="**/*.java"/>
    <exclude name="**/Resources/**"/>
    <modified>
      <param name="cache.cachefile" value="${basedir}/cache.${project}.fileset.myfiles.properties"/>
    </modified>
  </fileset>
  <target name="execute-some-command">
    <apply executable="javac" dir="${basedir}" failonerror="true">
      <fileset refid="myfiles"/>
    </apply>
  </target>
</project>
```

By default, the command will be executed once for every file.

If you need to use `parallel` to run the command only once, then use `maxparallel` to limit the amount of parallelism by passing at most this many sourcefiles at once (e.g. set to `1000` to pass a thousand files per run). For example:

```
<apply executable="javac" parallel="true" maxparallel="1000" dir="${basedir}">
  <fileset refid="myfiles"/>
</apply>
```

To see how many files you've got in total, check the content of cache file (look for `cache.cachefile` in above example).

Answer (score 1):

With a command that long you are likely running in to ARG_MAX at the shell.

This will report a good estimate of the available length, 

`expr getconf ARG_MAX - env|wc -c - env|wc -l * 4 - 2048`

[A nice article about command arg lists and length can be found here](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/)

Answer (score 1):

Run `ant -d`. This will produce capacious amounts of output. However, it will also show your entire compile line which may help you understand why it is so long.

Are you using Jenkins/Hudson and that's where the error occurs?

Try the following:

- Disable the build.
- Log into your build server, **AS YOUR JENKINS USER** and find the `workdir` directory where Jenkins/Hudson is attempting the build.
- You may have to change `$PATH` or set `$JAVA_HOME` to point to the JDK that Hudson/Jenkins is using.
- Now, run `ant -d`  *`<target>`* just as Jenkins/Hudson would. Pipe this output through `tee` into a file. Now, take a look and see what Hudson/Jenkins is doing and why `javac` has too many arguments.